# I can modify the static_url in settings.py?

Tags: django

Can I modify the `static_url` setting in `settings.py` to another value, such as `"/assets"`, without causing any issues?

Answer (score 0):

You can change that value to whatever you'd like, without any serious issues, provided you are correctly using the `{% static %}` template tag to resolve URL paths to static assets.